# How do I record on a 13" MBP?

Tags: microphone, recording

Where is the mic jack on a 13" MBP? I want to plug in a 3.5mm jack (like the iPod headphone size) into the MBP. How do I do that?

Comment: To clarify, by 1/8" jack, which size do you mean? 1/4" is the large jack typically associated with older and high end stereo equipment, 3.5mm is the standard consumer electronics headphone jack found on most things today (the size on an iPod), and 2.5mm (which is close to 1/8" in size) is the size you find on headset jacks on some cordless phones and assorted other less common items. If you're using anything other than 3.5mm, you'll need an adapter as well.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector

Comment: I am so sorry, I mean 35mm.

Comment: I'm guessing you really mean the [3.5mm TRS jack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector)

Comment: @bmike Yes I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physical location of the jack:
[image: Annotated 13" MBP diagram from Apple]

The audio-in jack on a 13" MBP is a [3.5mm combination TRS port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector).

It will sense standard analog or fiber optic connectors. It also works with TRS jacks for stereo audio out as well as a TRRS jack which allows microphone input as well as control from iPhone/iPod compatible remotes.

It can work as a headphone out, line-in, or digital audio in/out depending what's plugged into it. It can also accept an iPhone-compatible headset with mic and use the mic (and remote functions for music). Some non-amplified microphone input requires further hardware to properly deliver the signal. According to the [specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3627) it doesn't, but it seems like if it takes an iPhone headset mic, the signal will be delivered, but in a less usable form.

A popular USB connector like the [Griffin iMic](http://store.griffintechnology.com/imic) works well with more diverse input sources and contains an external D/A converter. The [iMic support FAQ](http://www.griffintechnology.com/support/imic) discusses the many aspects of sound capture and is a great reference on the topic.

[This instructables guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/133quot-Macbook-Pro-HeadphoneMic-Adapter/) on making a combination headphone+mic adapter might also be of use.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get a good-quality recording is to connect a microphone or audio signal to  an external analog-to-digital audio interface with a microphone preamplifier, which connects to the MacBook via USB 2.0 or FireWire 400.

There are many devices by many companies that perform this function. Here is one, the [AudioBox USB from Presonus](http://www.presonus.com/products/Detail.aspx?ProductId=53).

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, but I just needed to plug a standard 35mm mic straight into the computer. (I don't have the money right now for a USB/Firewire interface) Thanks for the suggestion!